# Rooms in Visual Studio Team Services - how to turn e-mail notifications on?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

We like the "rooms" feature of Visual Studio Team Services. Unfortunately, unlike slack, we do not get any e-mail notification when a message is posted there. I searched through many settings but I could not find a checkbox or anything to turn them on.

Without e-mail notifications the "rooms" are pretty pointless because I can ask my colleagues a question but they won't know until they coincidentally enter the rooms website.

We tried to address the colleague's with @Till but not even then an e-mail was sent. We all have provided our valid e-mail address in the profile settings. So, that is not the reason either.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I am aware that this is not 100% a code related question but I could not find a better place to ask. And it is something that might concern any ASP.net developer who works in a small team and likes to use visual studio for all aspects of work organisation :-)

[image]

Comment: Rooms has been removed from Visual Studio Team Services, so the Q can even be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn’t the feature of sending email notification in Team Room. I submitted a user voice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/17191415-vsts-team-room-message-alert) you can vote it.

For your requirement, you can achieve that though an app by using VSTS REST API.
For example:

1. Create an app
2. Call REST API to [get a list of rooms](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/chat/rooms#get-a-list-of-rooms)
3. Check lastActivity time of each room (e.g. compare pervious lastActivity time of the team room, then save current lastActivity time)
4. If lastActivity time is newer than pervious, [get a list of messages](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/chat/messages#get-a-list-of-messages) (could filter by time e.g. $filter=PostedTime ge 2016-11-21T02:26:16.137Z&api-version=1.0) and [get the list of users](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/chat/users) and check isOnline value
5. Check message content and send the email according some conditions.